# Klipfolio group by clarification

Tags: klipfolio

Need clarification on how lookup group and groupby work in klipfolio.
Having Data in the bellow json format:

```
{
  "44875": {
    "title": "Appointment - 1",
    "date": "01/12/2000",
    "appointment_date": "01/12/2000",
    "appointment_time": "12:00",
    "type": "Rent Request"
  },
  "44921": {
    "title": "Appointment - 2314",
    "date": "03/09/2007",
    "appointment_date": "03/10/2007",
    "appointment_time": "18:30",
    "type": "Sale Request"
  }
  "44922": {
    "title": "Appointment - 2311",
    "date": "03/09/2007",
    "appointment_date": "03/10/2007",
    "appointment_time": "18:30",
    "type": "Rent Request"
  },
  "44923": {
    "title": "Appointment - 2351",
    "date": "10/09/2007",
    "appointment_date": "03/10/2007",
    "appointment_time": "18:30",
    "type": "Rent Request"
  }
}
```

Final table view needs to be:

| Date | Type | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dec 2000 | Rent Request | 1 |
| Sep 2007 | Sales Request | 1 |
| Sep 2007 | Rent Request | 2 |

By using Lookup Group and GroupBy how do I work the aggregation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.